# Looking for a specific material for PCB coating

Tags: isolation, high-current

I am in the process of getting a PCB ready for mass production. The PCB has high-current traces (up to 32A) and in order to improve isolation and protect it from the environment I am looking to either coat it or what I think is probably a better solution: "potting" the whole PCB into the plastic casing.
The pcb does not need to be repairable and the enviroment is going to be the usual outside enviroment (-30 to 50 *C) The casing is going to be watertight but does not provide any shock absorbtion. It also needs to be flame retardent. THe pcb is for an electric car charger.

My question is if there is a certain material that exists that not only isolates, but also has at least a limited amount of heat-transferability, which would help a little bit with thermals, instead of just trapping the heat?

Coating would probably be better for thermals, but is coating enough for a device that's going to be exposed to high currents in an outside environment only protected by a plastic casing?

Comment: Telling us environment and what you wish the coating to achieve will help us to jelp you. "Conforma coatings" are usually appropriate.

Comment: Is there any intention for the device to be repairable? Conformal coating can be replaced, whereas de-potting can be destructive. Are there any high voltages present?

Comment: You can improve the thermal characteristics of a potting compound by mixing something like powdered aluminum in. Of course this would mean you should conformal coat the board before potting as using something like powdered aluminum in the potting would drastically change its electrical characteristics. But conformal coating before potting is a much safer idea anyway than not coating (even without modifying the potting compound) because many potting compounds shrink while curing, and I've had cases where this can tear small SMDs off the board.

Comment: Why do you need better isolation for high **current** traces? It is usually high **voltage** that leads to more isolation. Exactly what kind of "environment" are you expecting that would make your board need protection?

Answer (score 3):

There are a variety of electronics potting compounds available.
You can pick between various types of hardness, color and flame resistance.

Almost always two or more components and bubble free dispensing requires special equipment and handling.
Find a local coating and potting company nearby, there should be a few.

It is not cheap. If your product is not in a box that is easily topped of they need to design and mill a mold for your pcb further raising the costs.

You can buy small pouches of potting compounds on digikey for experiments. But you'll soon find that production with these is not time effective.